# HTTP transport error: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL

Tags: web-services, jax-rpc

I am using a Stub Based client Approach for JAX RPC
This is my Client

```
package com;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import com.client.BookCatalog;
import com.client.BookCatalogService;
import com.client.BookCatalogService_Impl;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws RemoteException {

        BookCatalogService_Impl service = new BookCatalogService_Impl();

        BookCatalog bc = service.getBookCatalogPort();
        System.out.println(bc.getBookPrice("Web Services"));

    }

}
```

**Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.RemoteException: HTTP transport error: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL; nested exception is:
HTTP transport error: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL
at com.client.BookCatalog_Stub.getBookPrice(BookCatalog_Stub.java:87)
at com.Client.main(Client.java:19)
Caused by: HTTP transport error: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.http.HttpClientTransport.invoke(HttpClientTransport.java:148)
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:96)
at com.client.BookCatalog_Stub.getBookPrice(BookCatalog_Stub.java:70)
... 1 more**

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more specific version of your web service client class constructor, for example:

```
java.net.URL wsdlLocation = new URL("http://service.com/services/Service?wsdl");
javax.xml.namespace.QName qualifiedServiceName = 
    new QName("http://you.service.namespace", "ServiceName");
BookCatalogService_Impl service = 
    new BookCatalogService_Impl(wsdlLocation, qualifiedServiceName);
...
```

I was using a constructor that takes only the WSDL location and was getting the same error. Adding the second parameter solved my problem.

Hope this helps!